# How to share a URL with fragment in Safari on iPadOS

Tags: safari, share, ipados, url-fragment

When I open a URL that ends in a fragment with Safari on iPadOS 15 (e.g. `https://example.com/page#heading`), Safari will scroll to the position identified by the fragment (`heading`). But when I then try to share that URL via Mail, the URL entered into the mail's body does not include the fragment (`https://example.com/page`). So only a link to the top of the page is shared.

This also happens with URLs that have a slash before the hash tag (`https://example.com/page/#heading`).

How can I share a URL with its fragment via Mail in Safari on iPadOS?

Answer (score 1):

The only easy way I've found is to select the url in the top url bar and copy it from there. That will maintain the fragment, but I strongly agree that a setting to always do this would be super useful. I'm not a fan of this change from Apple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is the cumbersome procedure I'm using now. I still hope that Apple fixes this or - unlikely - someone comes up with a better solution. That's why I'm reluctant to accept your answer. Not sure about Stackoverflow policies here, though.